# Like count from the Facebook plugin (without making another request to the Graph) Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins, graph

Is it possible to get the the number of likes from the Facebook like [plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) without using Facebook graph?

I already tried manually digging into the iFrame and get this error:

```
sdk.js:90 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "mysite.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

Also looked into the Facebook API [events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8)

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: No, that is of course not possible, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: alright, cool. after reading up on same origin policy [link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67889/why-do-browsers-enforce-the-same-origin-security-policy-on-iframes#67891) that makes sense. I guess there is no way to do this then unless Facebook have implemented something?
it is possible to get the comment count like so:
<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="mysite.com">0</div>
not for likes though, either way this approach involves another element so may as well use graph...

Comment: The API _is_ what Facebook has implemented ;-) And the equivalent of the comments counter is the like button.